# jQuery code not working properly on sticking a div after scrolling a certain amount

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a website for me and I want a div in it which scrolls for certain amount and then gets fixed. I can do that much but am experiencing some unexpected problem.

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
    Something...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
padding-left:340px;
background:yellow;
border-bottom:2px solid black;
height:45px;
top:150px;
}
.stick
{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
}
html{height:2000px}
```

and **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var s = $(".nav");
var pos = s.position();                    
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        s.addClass("stick");
    } else {
        s.removeClass("stick"); 
    }
});
});
```

**JSfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/4J4JE/

Please help it gets back to its origional position and doesn't scroll further and thanx.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to go back to its original position, then remove the `else` part of your `if (windowpos >= pos.top)` conditional, so that the `stick` class doesn't get removed when you scroll back up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = $(".nav");
  var pos = s.position();                    
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
      s.addClass("stick");
    }
  });
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4J4JE/1/).

Comment: Thanx zakang, but still when I scroll down the amount for the jQuery to run, the scrollbar still gets back to the top, and It is still fixed, I want such that it scrolls for the first 150px till the top touches the div, and then get fixed at the top.